# Tag cleanup: Delete the tag [collecting]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

There are currently five questions with the tag [collecting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/collecting), some of them has some relation to collection, list... 
I don't even understand the meaning of this tag, neither can imagine an expert of collecting (as it's related to this site).

Can we get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we typically wait for community consensus on tag cleanups, meh, there's only 4, and its not quite right on most of them. The tag has been properly mauled. Let me know if I missed any